# I'm using magento 1.9 and i want to display 4 items in a list block but layout breaks?

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, product-list

I'm using magento 1.9 and i want to display 4 items in a list block 
ex: `{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="411" column_count="4" &nbsp;mode="grid" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}`, then magento display 4 items correct! but in a row below it should show next 4 items side by side and that not happen magento show 1 item and break to next line showing again 4 items.

Comment: i've already try with limit and count but nothing this worked.

Comment: Are you using a custom theme? It sounds like there is a hard coded `% 5` in `list.phtml`.

Comment: i'm using a  rwd theme.

Comment: *the* `rwd/default` theme or *a* rwd theme?

Comment: @fschmengler could tell me in what tag is the  % 5 ?

Comment: @fschmengler this rwd/default

Comment: `%` is the modulo operator, and by default used to add the `last` class to the last item in each row: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml#L126 my suspicion was that it's hard coded to 5, i.e. "every fifth item", instaead of using `column_count` properly.

Comment: i looked the code it is not hard coded
@fschmengler see the page http://www.livrariagutenberg.com.br/

Comment: Next thing I would look for is `:nth-child` in the CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure but problem could be in your CSS, view source code I found that one which you may try. It shows product side by side when you change `clear: left to clear: none`

```
.products-grid--max-6-col > li:nth-child(6n+1) {
        clear: left; /* if this is clear: none*/
}
```